# How is the word 바라건대 ('hopefully') formed?

Tags: word-formation

I know the word '바라다', meaning to 'hope'.

바라건대 is translated as 'hopefully', but how is it derived from '바라다'?

Comment: http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=1583800

Comment: http://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?mode=LSD&mid=sec&sid1=102&oid=081&aid=0002033712

Comment: *말하는 사람이 자신의 생각이나 의견을 말하겠다고 미리 알릴 때 사용한다* seems this prefix shows that the following phrase is the speaker's personal opinion, may be that's why it's translated into *hopefully*. May be finding out how 듣건대, 보건대 get translated will give some more insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know the word '바라다'

In Korean, '~건대' emphasizes the following sentence or showㄴsthe purpose of speaker.

So, the word '바라다'+'~건대' = '바라건대' means that the speaker hopes to do something and he's about to say what it is.

There is thread of connection between '바라건대' and 'hopefully'.